# Element click vs Document click preference

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a parent div with id `test-container` and inside this are child divs with class `icon-btn`.

When I click anywhere in parent-div a new child-div element is appended to parent-div at the location of click.

**Problem** is when I click on child-div element parent-div event fires first and then child-div event fires. I would like child-div event to fire first.

JS:

```
$('#test-container').on('click', function(e) {
  alert('clicked');
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  var relX = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  var relY = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  $(this).append('<div class="icon-btn" style="top: ' + relX + 'px; left: ' + relY + 'px; display: block; position: absolute; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ffffff; overflow: visible; box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; z-index: 16; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 15px 14px; color: #fff; cursor: pointer;" id="icon-btn-1"></div>')
});;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.icon-btn', function() {
    alert('clicked sub div');
  });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div style="width: 300px; position: relative;">
  <img src="http://www.flowermeaning.com/flower-pics/Daffodil-Meaning.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="100%" height="100%">
  <div id="test-container" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; cursor: crosshair; left: 0px; width: 300px; height: 200px; z-index: 8;">
    <div class="icon-btn" style="top: 45px; left: 184px; display: block; position: absolute; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ffffff; overflow: visible; box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; z-index: 16; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 15px 14px; color: #fff; cursor: pointer;"
id="icon-btn-1"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Please see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Abhig10/x95owvL8/7/) for working example.

Comment: Try this : $(document).on('click','#test-container', function(e) {

instance of $('#test-container').on('click', function(e) {
https://jsfiddle.net/x95owvL8/8/

Comment: @kag yeah that works. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//$('#test-container').on('click', function(e) {
// this is all about the binding of element

```
    $(document).on('click','#test-container', function(e) {
  alert('parent div');
  var parentOffset = $(this).offset();
  var relX = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  var relY = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
  $(this).append('<div class="icon-btn" style="top: ' + relX + 'px; left: ' + relY + 'px; display: block; position: absolute; border-radius: 3px; border: 1px solid #ffffff; overflow: visible; box-shadow: 0 0 2px #000; z-index: 16; width: 50px; height: 50px; padding: 15px 14px; color: #fff; cursor: pointer;" id="icon-btn-1"></div>')
});;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on('click', '.icon-btn', function() {
    alert('child sub div');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`Document click` will work also for dynamically added elements with that class.

`Element click` works only for those elements which are ready after `DOM` loads. If you will add elements with that selector, `element click` will not work for them.

Comment: I understand that. But what I want is that the `document click` should trigger before `element click`.

Answer (score 0):

When you append new element to the parent the previous events attached to the will not work for new one.
You can simply remove previous and attach the same event again to have the desired effect

```
    $('.selectorOfYourDynamicChild').off("click").on('click', function(e) { 
      // Your logic goes here
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the way you attach the click event on child divs, like:

```
`$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.icon-btn').on("click", function() {
    alert("child sub div");
  });
});`
```